Implement a trait for multiple generic traits
I'm trying to implement a trait for Display and Debug traits, but rust responds with conflicting implementations.
Here is my code:
pub trait AsString {
    fn as_string(self) -> String;
}

impl<T: Display> AsString for T {
    fn as_string(self) -> String {
        self.to_string()
    }
}

impl<T: Debug> AsString for T {
    fn as_string(self) -> String {
        format!("{:?}", self)
    }
}

But rust gives me:
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `AsString`
  --> src/convert_test_result.rs:43:1
   |
37 | impl<T: Display> AsString for T {
   | ------------------------------- first implementation here
...
43 | impl<T: Debug> AsString for T {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation

How can I solve the issue?

Sorry, but this is currently impossible to do in stable rust.

What if T is Display + Debug ?

You can somewhat simulate the required behavior, but (partially) in runtime, using the impls crate, or the idea it is based upon outlined in the (non-accepted) answer to this question

@EugeneSh. great idea, thank you, this might be a solution for me in the end!

@EugeneSh. unfortunately this didn't work for me as it requires a knowledge of specific types upfront.

Yeah. It is quite limited. I also looked at this which might help with certain use-case, but not as generic as yours...

So what is your desired behaviour if T is Display + Debug? I think that question really is the important one here.

@Finomnis I prefer Display over Debug. So it would be great if rust forced me to define From<Display>, From<Debug> and From<Display + Debug> to have a clear behavior.

While that might be possible to do in this case, this behavior isn't generalizable. If the two crates were from two different crates, which crate would be responsible for implementing the combined one?
I know this is a limitation, but one that has its reasons. In most cases it can be worked around in one way or another. I'm afraid that's just how it is.

Unfortunately, negative trait bounds is not yet part of stable Rust.
If it was, you could do something like this:
pub trait AsString {
    fn as_string(self) -> String;
}

impl<T> AsString for T
where
    T: Debug + !Display
{
    fn as_string(self) -> String {
        format!("{:?}", self)
    }
}

impl<T> AsString for T
where
    T: Display + !Debug
{
    fn as_string(self) -> String {
        self.to_string()
    }
}

impl<T> AsString for T
where
    T: Debug + Display
{
    fn as_string(self) -> String {
        // you would have to choose which implementation
        // to use if a type is both Display and Debug
    }
}

However, the example you provided would never work in the way you've written it.

Any idea when negative trait bound can become part of stable Rust?
